# How to write a function that returns a changed string based on width height and depth

Tags: python, string, function, replace, computer-science

The idea is to write a function that takes in a string, integer row, column and depth index, character n, and an integer for width, an integer for height and an integer for depth as inputs. This function then should return a copy of the string but with the character at the given row, column and depth index replaced by n. For example:

```
      >>>function(‘.XXvv..vV..XXX.vVxv’, 0, 0, 0, ‘#’, 3, 3, 2)
      ‘#XXvv..vV..XXX.vVxv’
```

I have no idea how to do that. I’m not sure if the following information is needed to solve the above function, but the problem before this one was to create a function that takes in a string, integer row and column index, character n, and integer width and height as inputs. This new function would return a copy of the string but with the character at the given row and column index replaced by n. For example:

```
      >>>new_function(‘..x..x..x’, 1, 1, ‘#’, 3, 3)
      ‘..x.#x..x’
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you draw the incoming string (`..x..x..x`) as a grid, like:

```
..x
..x
..x
```

Then, a grid of the indices of the string that make up that grid:

```
012
345
678
```

So, if, for example, `row` is `1`, and `column` is `1`, then it's index `4` that has to change. The pattern in this case is `index = (row * width) + column`. In this example, that would be `index = (1 * 3) + 1`.

```
def new_function(string, row, column, char, width, height):
    if len(string) != width * height:
        # Something is wrong.
        # Do something here?
        pass

    # Turn the string into a list of individual characters.
    chars = list(string)

    # Calculate the index of the character we want to change.
    index = (row * width) + column

    # Replace the character at 'index' with 'char'.
    chars[index] = char

    # Turn the list of characters back into a string, and return it.
    return "".join(chars)

print(new_function('..x..x..x', 1, 1, '#', 3, 3))
```